# Create custom https URL

Tags: url, web, https

how is made a https url like this? [image: generic url]

Can i add custom info after padlock (like "Codex Non Sufficit")?

Answer (score 1):

You need to buy an Extended Validation (EV) certificate. It's more expensive and you need to provide more information to get it.

Note: If you have an EV certificate, browsers can decide to NOT show that information if your page contains mixed content (http resources)

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-do-i-tell-if-my-connection-is-secure#w_green-padlock

Answer (score 0):

*Code Non Sufficit LC* is the Organization (O) from the SSL certificate, *US* is the Country (C). Only way to change this text is to issue a certificate with an organization name with the desired text.

Comment: My SSL certificate contains that info. My question, now, is : Why are those data visible on some websites but not on others?